# How to test Arquillian test class written for Hibernate entity?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

I am new to Arquillian and trying to configure to test a Hibernate Entity. It's datasource is managed on tomcat 6 server.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to have a look at the [guides on the Arquillian website](http://arquillian.org/guides/). They offer gentle introduction to all the mechanics you need to understand.